# Loop through Object Initializer

Tags: c#, object-initializers

How can I optimize the following piece of code?

```
IList<OrderItem> OrderItemsList = new List<OrderItem>();
while (orderItemsResult.Read())
{
    new OrderItem()
    {
        ItemName = orderItemsResult.GetString("item_name"),
        Price = orderItemsResult.GetFloat("price"),
        Quantity = orderItemsResult.GetInt32("quantity")
    },
}
```

Comment: could you be more specific - whats wrong & what you want to do?

Comment: I guess you want to `Add()` the new `OrderItem` to `OrderItemsList`?

Comment: Am trying to populate the DB results to the object initialization array but it returned 0 results. I have already checked the DB query and it is fine. I need to populate these objects for Runtime Text Template.

Comment: Use this inside `while` => `OrderItemsList.Add(new OrderItem
                    {
                        ItemName = orderItemsResult.GetString("item_name"),
                        Price = orderItemsResult.GetFloat("price"),
                        Quantity = orderItemsResult.GetInt32("quantity")
                    });`

Comment: Thanks @er-sho haha! Am such a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a bit late to reply ,still I shall add my thoughts. 
We can do without `List<OrderItem>` object.
The below code returns `IEnumerable<OrderItem>`

```
while (orderItemsResult.Read())
{
   yield return new OrderItem()
   {
        ItemName = orderItemsResult.GetString("item_name"),
        Price = orderItemsResult.GetFloat("price"),
        Quantity = orderItemsResult.GetInt32("quantity")
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajeet! Much appreciated. I never thought there are numerous ways of doing this. Great help for a week old c# developer like me.

Answer (score 0):

As @crowcoder and @er-sho pointed out in the comments, you need to add the `OrderItem` to `OrderItemsList`:

```
IList<OrderItem> OrderItemsList = new List<OrderItem>();
while (orderItemsResult.Read())
{
    var orderItem = new OrderItem()
    {
        ItemName = orderItemsResult.GetString("item_name"),
        Price = orderItemsResult.GetFloat("price"),
        Quantity = orderItemsResult.GetInt32("quantity")
    };

    // add to the list
    OrderItemsList.Add(orderItem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

As in the accepted answer, you can implement it as an iterator function, but keep in mind that in case orderedItemsResult is an IDisposable such as IDataReader for reading from something like a database (the methods called on it appear that this is the case) to make sure to embed it in a try/finally or using block.
For example:

```
IEnumerable<OrderItem> GetOrders(string connectionString, string queryString)
{
    IDbConnection connection = new MyDbConnection(connectionString);
    IDbCommand command = null;
    IDbReader orderedItemsResult = null;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command = new MyCommand(queryString, connection);
        orderedItemsResult = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (orderItemsResult.Read())
        {
            yield return new OrderItem()
            {
                ItemName = orderItemsResult.GetString("item_name"),
                Price = orderItemsResult.GetFloat("price"),
                Quantity = orderItemsResult.GetInt32("quantity")
            };
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        orderItemsResult?.Dispose();
        command?.Dispose();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The IEnumerable returned which implements IDisposable as well executes the finally block whenever it is disposed (for example, when a foreach is done with it)